# Why my IFS function is not working with QUERY?

Tags: google-sheets, ifs

When I use `IF` it works perfectly.

```
=IF(H6="Vaga", QUERY(A2:D60, "SELECT * WHERE A "&H3&" 
"&H9&"'"),QUERY(A2:D60, "SELECT * WHERE C "&H3&" '"&H9&"'"))
```

But when I try `IFS`, it says there is an error with number of rows and columns

```
=IFS(H6="Vaga", QUERY(A2:D60, "SELECT * WHERE A "&H3&" '"&H9&"'"), 
H6="Empresa", QUERY(A2:D60, "SELECT * WHERE C "&H3&" '"&H9&"'"), 
H6="Postada", QUERY(A2:D60, "SELECT * WHERE E "&H3&" '"&H9&"'"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it's not working, but `IFS` has some limitations with arrays and likely with `query`. However an easy solution to your formula would seem to be just to extrapolate out multiple if statements:

```
=IF(H6="Vaga", QUERY(A2:D60, "SELECT * WHERE A "&H3&" '"&H9&"'"),
  if(H6="Empresa", QUERY(A2:D60, "SELECT * WHERE C "&H3&" '"&H9&"'"),
  If(H6="Postada", QUERY(A2:D60, "SELECT * WHERE E "&H3&" '"&H9&"'"),"nothing")))
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:D60, "where "&
 CHOOSE(MATCH(H6, {"Vaga","Empresa","Postada"}, ), "A","C","E")&H3&" '"&H9&"'")
```

see:  **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124685/186471**

Comment: This formula looks better, but didn't work =(

Comment: @DanielPirozzi can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: No worries, mate. I used the other guy's formula. It's for a small project. Thank you so much.